# HTML Page stops scrolling when I hit top or bottom of the page

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site that was put together by a team in India, there are several pages and only one stylesheet used in all of them.
In one of the pages (only one our of 50 or so pages) I see very strange behaviour!
Sometimes after the page is loaded scroll is disabled and the only way to see bottom of the page is to use tab to move to items that can't be seen!
Sometimes it works initially but as soon as I hit the top or bottom of the page and page bounces back the scrolling functionality stops!

I don't want to sound stupid but I've looked and can't point my finger at when and what disables the scroll function.

Page uses bootstrap and jquery, nothing fancy really.

Any idea?

Comment: @jaunt Please [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice): "If you don't have time to say something politely, just leave it for someone who does."

Comment: Or, as every page uses the same stylesheet, try just adding `html {overflow-y: scroll;}` at the top :)

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Fair point. I'm sorry for coming across as so rude. But the message still stands:  we do need more information.

Comment: @jaunt Completely agreed with the message, just not the delivery.

Comment: I don't think that was THAT rude.. just a rant. :) Keep it friendly !

Comment: Guys, I didn't mind it, as I mentioned myself even writing it I felt stupid but again I thought maybe there is simple explanation! Anyways, the url is [link](http://cbr-portal.appspot.com) and if you use test@pandr.com for username and pandr123 as password you can see first hand the issue. Hope this help and thanks for all the nice comments ;)

Comment: @AmirPeivandi It is working fine for me, are you using IE8 by chance?

Comment: @Adam No I used Chrome and Safari on Mac

Comment: Nevermind I see the issue now :)\

Comment: Thanks to Callan, adding html {overflow-y: scroll;} worked like a charm! But still like to know why it works on some pages and not on the landing page?!

Comment: @AmirPeivandi that was just a simple hack/fix that was likely to solve the issue, not the root of the problem! Glad your issue has now been resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

```
.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

From your css